# Is there a browser-based Websocket listener implementation?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, browser, websocket

I am interested to know if anyone has built a javascript websocket listener for a browser.  Basically the server side of a websocket that runs in a client.  This would allow messages to be sent to the client directly.  Why?  Because instead of having a Node.js, python, java, etc, server process sitting on or near the client/browser, I can just use a thread in the browser as a listening server thread.  I don't think that any browsers support this currently.

I've run across answers like this:  https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2316132

Just curious if anyone has done this.  I believe that the current Websockets spec does not support listeners on the browser.  It would make the deployment of various peer-to-peer applications a bit easier to deploy.

Comment: Would you like to create code for your server directly on the page with a Javascript client?

Comment: You can stream data directly to the client with WebSockets .... check out [socket.io](http://socket.io) for some nice abstractions.

Comment: >> Would you like to create code for your server directly on the page with a Javascript client  - Yes, in principle.  I'm not saying this is a good idea, just if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

[WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/getting-started/overview) allows for peer-to-peer connections to be made between browsers.

You would still need a server in order for individual users to discover each other but then they could connect directly to each other rather than having to pass all their traffic via a central server.

Answer (score 0):

The idea.

You can use a simple **echo server** written in any language. Your script can send the data to the server then get it back, handle it on the same page with different functions/classes emulating the real server.

An example: http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

Then, you can think about different formats of packets to/from server to diffirentiate them inside one script.